# Rails variable photos on document

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

This is a generic question. My wife has company that has one-of-a-kind products such as the photo showed.

The challenge is, she wants to be able to create something like what is shown without doing it manually. The challenge is the products/photos are constantly changing so the photos that show would have to be dynamic and show the inventory.

Sometimes there are 20 products/photos other times there are 40... it seems to me the challenge would be in the view and changing the amount of photos that show up based on the change in inventory.

Thanks for your thoughts, this is a great community.

[image: The challenge]

Comment: The problem as I see it is one of management.  Each time a new product is created, you'll have to add a photo.  Each time it's out of stock, you'll have to remove it from 'available' and each time it's in stock, you'll have to movie it again.  The view itself is quite simple, if you like the layout in the photo; iterate through the records and make sure the number of records you request is divisible by 3.  This will be an app you'll put together in a day or two to start.  Making yourself (or your wife) keep up to date with the necessary inventory will be the real challenge. :)  Best of luck.

Comment: Hi, this question is a bit broad - you're asking us to help you design a whole system. Generally Stack Overflow works best when you have a go at designing it yourself, and come and ask for help when you hit a particular snag - either you have an error needing debugging or have the kind of question that has a "right answer". broad questions lead to long discussions that aren't really the right fit here... perhaps you could find a mentor in your local ruby community to discuss the broad strokes, then come back here with specifics? :)

Answer (score 0):

What I would do in this case is have a couple of models

1) Client - the peroson whom the product is for this would look like:

- id
- name

2) Album - this is how we can group all the photos in a collection

- id
- client_id
- name

3) Image - this are the actual images you want to use in the collection

- id
- album_id
- file
- display_order

if you are still having question just ask 
I will try to build a demo of of this.